# Rounded border around plot in R

Tags: r, border

I need to put smooth border around plot. code

```
plot(0:10, 0:10, type="n", xlab="X", ylab="Y")

box("figure", col="blue")
```

instead of simple blue line, how i can put smooth grey line with rounded corners?

[image: example]

many thanks.

Comment: it just change the colour of line. i want bit thick and curve corners instead of just square box

Comment: I edited your post to make that clearer. I'm not sure there's a way to make it appear around the figure by default, but [roundrect](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grid/html/grid.roundrect.html) in the grid package is a good place to start

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
library(grid)

plot(0:10, 0:10, type="n", xlab="X", ylab="Y")
grid.roundrect(gp=gpar(fill="#00000000", col="grey"))
```

[image]

If you find the borders are being cut off, you can always reduce the size of the rounded rectangle:

```
plot(0:10, 0:10, xlab="X", ylab="Y")
grid.roundrect(height=0.99, width=0.99, gp=gpar(fill="#00000000", col="grey"))
```

[image]

Comment: how i can make it bit thicker?

Comment: Add a `lwd` argument to `gpar`. For example: `grid.roundrect(width=0.99, height=0.99,gp=gpar(fill="#00000000", col="grey", lwd=2))`