# r plot legend box corner round

Tags: r, plot, legend

In R how to make legend box corner round.
An example figure is: 
[image]

Here legend has round shape corner and shadow.
How to achieve this in R?

I tried this:

```
plot(1:10, type="l")
legend("topleft", c("line"), lty=1, box.lty=1, box.lwd=2, box.col="blue")
```

It can change box border color but I can't find option to change the shape of box.

Comment: what was the first thing you tried

Comment: i tried many things including looking at ?legend , but can't find any hint!

Comment: Using base graphics you'd probably want to take a look at [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11663382/rounded-border-around-plot-in-r) as a starting point.  Basically you'd want to draw your rounded rectangles (one below the other to mimic the dropshadow with appropriate shading) and then plot your legend over the top without a border.